# NumberFormatException for input string: "9.014", when trying to set value of formField

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, pdf-form

I am working with `iText-7`, and trying to read a `pdfForm` (generated in `LibreOffice`) and set value for one text field (Form has only one text field). But I am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9.014"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:867)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.splitDAelements(PdfFormField.java:2114)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.getFontAndSize(PdfFormField.java:2058)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.regenerateField(PdfFormField.java:1639)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:939)
at com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:900)
```

when executing

```
form.getField(key).setValue("1234567890");
```

Here, is the code for performing above task:

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
    Map<String, PdfFormField> tf = form.getFormFields();

    for (String key : tf.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: |" + key + "| \t value: " + 
        tf.get(key).getValueAsString());
        form.getField(key).setValue("1234567890");
    }

        pdf.close();
```

I am able to read the value of the field, but not able to write back.

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J8C6qBOcQnX7nJvki7uGRI_UAHCsxvhs/view) to the pdf

Comment: this is link to the pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J8C6qBOcQnX7nJvki7uGRI_UAHCsxvhs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the exact iText-7 version you are using ?

Comment: @Arnaud its 7.0.0